# Cannot install fastparquet in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, parquet, fastparquet

I am trying to install fastparquet in order to write a csv into a parquet file. Using jupyter notebook, python 3, 
the cell does not show any result after running the Following command:

`pip install fastparquet`

I run another simple command and it show the result. I installed another packages and it work perfectly but fastparquet does not installed without showing any error.
So, 
How do I go about fixing this ?

Comment: try: 
%pip install fastparquet
or 
%conda install  fastparquet